# Printing issues when moving from Python 2 to 3 with code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabs

I have a code that I am trying to convert but it's written in Python 2 and I would like to print this code in Python 3. However, it's not able to print in matrix format. I am getting output in an unrecognizable table format.

The code is following:

```
 for n in cols:
    print('/t',n),
print
cost = 0

for g in sorted(costs):
    print('\t', g)
    for n in cols:
        y = res[g][n]
        if y != 0:
            print (y),
        cost += y * costs[g][n]
        print ('\t'),
    print
print ("\n\nTotal Cost = ", cost)
```

The expected output is in the following format:

```
|0 |A |B |C |D |E |
|- |- |- |- |- |- |
|W |  |  |20|  |  |        
|X |  |40|10|  |20|  
|Y |  |20|  |  |30|      
|Z |  |  |  |  |60|  


Total Cost =  1000
```

Could you suggest what changes I need to make in this code?

Comment: You need to use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. What specific difficulties are you having in using it?

Comment: I have updated my code. I did try print() but was still not able to get the right output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In py 2 *print* did not have parenthesis, in py3 is a must.

###### python3 simple print

```py
# in py3 a print must be like
print("my text")
```

###### python3 print with no newline / carriage return

Also in your py2 code you have `print ('\t'),`  please mind the **comma** after *print* => which means do not add a newline after print.
In python3 would translate to

```py
print('\t', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` calls must always be enclosed in parenthesis like this:

```py
print("\t", n)
```

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect print(), however, still no joy

Comment: You still have commas following the last parenthesis in some cases and also some lines containing only `print`. What are they supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing - whenever you see the Python 2 print command with
a comma at the end, such as

```py
print y,
```

you need to change that line to:

```py
print(y,end="")
```

This will print the variable without a new line.